# external json to acces in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I access `categories.name_category` in Javascript? Everything is working for the AJAX call to the REST API:

[image]

I tried to do like this but its not working:

[image]

I use Moustache framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see why this was closed. Sure, the OP could do with some guidance about putting code in images, but all relevant information is there. I'm voting to re-open this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`categories` is an array of objects, so you need to use `{{categories[0].name_category}}` - assuming you only want the first value.